# is it possible to do lens like traverse on data

Tags: haskell

Say we have this following data definition

```
data Test = Test
  { _intMember :: Int
  , _strMember :: String
  , _dblMember :: Double
  }
```

I want to encode the data structure into a ByteString like this:

```
encode :: Test -> ByteString
encode test = pack $ show (test ^. intMember) `append` show (test ^. strMember) `append` show (test ^. dblMember)
```

Very straightforward. However, in reality I have a data with like 50 redords and it becomes really unpleasant quickly. What make it even worse is that I have dozens of data definitions like this one. It would be best if `toListOf` from the Lens library would work on the custom data but apparently a generic custom data is not `Getting` type that function works with. So my question is what is the best way to reduce boilerplate as much as I could? To make it simple, lets assume all records I need to deal with are instances of the `Show` class. Thanks for reading.

Comment: `folded` will only work if you have data all of the same type. Lens cannot (easily) extract all members of a record into a sequence type if those members do not have the same type. You are probably looking for generics, e.g. `syb` or `GHC.Generics`. More importantly, there are already plenty of libraries for serializing and deserializing Haskell datatypes.